# -1 df for a saturated model with ML estimator?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, structural-equation-modeling, degrees-of-freedom

I estimate a saturated / just-identified model (specifically: an APIM model, actor-partner-interdepence model) with the R package `lavaan`.

This model is saturated and should have 0 $df$. This is true for the "GLS" generalized least squares estimator. With "ML" maximum likelihood estimation, however, it has **-1** $df$ according to the output.

**Can somebody explain why there's a df of -1 with maximum likelihood estimation?**

Comment: I agree "-1 df" doesn't seem sensible output for any statistical model. Think you may need to email the authors of the package.

Comment: Jarrett Byrnes, one of the authors of `lavaan`, asked some questions on CV recently. Let's hope he can answer that. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Yves Rosseel, the maintainer of the `lavaan`package. He is very helpful in answering questions about the package, and he explained it as following to me.

The problem was a covariance between two exogenous variables in the model. When the estimator is set to `"ML"`, all exogenous x covariates by default are kept out of the model. That means, their variances and covariances are not estimated (this is the effect of setting the parameter `fixed.x` to `TRUE`).

If the covariance is included in the model syntax, it is forced to be estimated, costing an extra degree of freedom **(--> this leads to -1 $df$!)**.

The different $df$ between the `ML`and the `GLS` estimator are due to different default presets in `lavaan`: If `estimator="GLS"` or `"WLS"`, `fixed.x` is `FALSE` by default, if `estimator="ML"` it's `TRUE`by default.

Two solutions to overcome the -1 $df$ issue:

1. Remove the covariance from the model
2. Explicitly specify 'fixed.x=FALSE' when using the "ML" estimator